How to the fetch() function in PyScript with options
I am confused about the use of the fetch() function in PyScript.
There seems to be two versions of that function:

from the js module
from the pyscript module

Only the first one seems to accept two arguments.
I want to include header informations like so:
request_options = {
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": { "charset": "UTF-8" }
}
        
url = "https://www.nanobooks23.de/material/schachclub2.json"
response = await fetch(
  "https://corsproxy.io/?" + url,
  request_options
)

This only works with the fetch() function from the js module.
Otherwise I'll receive an
TypeError: fetch() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
So, how can I include the headers when using the fetch() function from the pyscript module?
I am using PyScript version 2024.9.2


All the other except the url argument are keyword arguments, the url is the only positional argument.
Pass the arguments directly as body = body or use **{options}.
You cant pass them without keywords inside an object.

When calling fetch like this
response = await fetch(
"https://corsproxy.io/?" + url,
method = "GET",
headers =  { "charset": "UTF-8" }
)
I'll receive an "pyodide.ffi.JsException: TypeError: Failed to fetch"
PS: I looks like another answer and my comment had been deleted?

I think that specifically with headers, you should wrap the object by headers = to_js({headers})

Now I'll get an "TypeError: Object of type JsProxy is not JSON serializable" error - I have to do some more research, but it works with fetch() from the js module

Im just going to the pyscript docs for giving answers, they are very comfortable and they are searchable so you can refer to them. Specifically on using headers - in the doc example, when using headers, they create an object of headers, wrap it with to_js, take all options including the "js" headers and put in another object, arranged with the names "headers=jsheaders" etc. and wrap all the options object by another to_js, and then give it to fetch as options=options

It just don't work for me when using something simple like headers={  "Content-Type": "application/json"}. It always leads to an pyodide.ffi.JsException: TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource. When leaving out headers and just providing url and method with the fetch() function from PyScript it works. I could not find anything in the PyScript docu.

It has probably something to do with the corsproxy.io I am using
